# Condition on $ a$ and $b$ so that $f(x)$ has a root?

Tags: functions

Let $f(x) = ax(1-bx^{2/3})-1$  where $a$ and $b$ are positive. What is the necessary and sufficient condition on $a$ and $b$ such that $f(x)$ has at least one real root?

Comment: sorry, edited. I missed the -1 at the end

Comment: What do you mean by "at least one root"? It should be "at least one real root", right?

Comment: good call, thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(0) = -1 < 0$ for any choice of $a$ and $b$.

$\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}f(x) = +\infty$ for any choice of $a>0$ and $b>0$.

So for any $a, b>0$ there is some $M$ so that $f(x)>0$ if $x<-M$. By the Intermediate Value Theorem, $f$ has a root for some $x$ in the interval $[-M,0]$.

You can also play around with different values of $a$ and $b$ on desmos.com which is always fun:

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9ln4kemfwf

Comment: OH yeah, I'm an idiot. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Thinking about it more, you can show that there is always a root unless $a=0$. If $a$ and $b$ have the same sign, it is a negative root. If they have opposite sign it is a positive root. If $b=0$ it is $x=\frac{1}{a}$.

Comment: SO i'm trying to code this up using binary search and the computer doesn't like doing arithmetic with negative infinity. So for a given $a$ and $b$. How can I find an $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)$ is guaranteed to be positive? I'm not familiar with the convention here. Should I create a new question? Thanks!

Comment: Use a loop: start with x_0 = -1 and while f(x_0) < 0, set x_0 = 2x_0.

Comment: oh yeah right, that's smart, thanks! I was thinking of coming up with a formula for $x_0$

Comment: You could probably do that too, but I'm feeling lazy. You might also consider Newton's method for finding the root since $f$ is differentiable except at $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f(x) $ is continue in $\mathbb{R}$ and $f(0) = -1 $,if we assume $f(1) = a(1-b) - 1 > 0$ and using The Zero Theorem, then we can get at least one point $x_{0} \in (0,1) $ such that $f(x_{0} ) = 0$.

Maybe helps you .

Comment: Hi askuyue, thanks for replying. Sorry I didn't make it clear. I'm looking for the necessary and sufficient condition so that given a and b I can say if(condition) --> function has a root, else function doesn't have a root, if that makes sense. Thank you